# How do you redraw a fragment?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments

I have an application that has tabs that display fragments.  The problem I have is one of the tabs loads another activity which then writes to a database.  When the user finishes that activity and returns to the fragment I want the fragment to check the database and hide or display UI elements.  I can check the db just fine. I just can't find anyway to modify the UI when returning to the fragment.

I've tried to .invalidate() the view.
I've tried to place all the redraw UI stuff in onResume() and it never gets called.

I'm feeling that it should have something to do with my Tab FragmentActivity.  This is what I have there.

```
@Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (mFragment == null) {
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName(), mArgs);
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
            ft.commit();
        } else {
            ft.attach(mFragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
```

It's still not redrawing the tab.

How can I do this?  I am also open to other ways to tackle the problem more generally if anyone has better ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved my own question.  It might be a hack and had nothing to do with with the onTabReselected() but the solution is the following.

In the AndroidManifest.xml I add the following line to the tab activity:

```
android:stateNotNeeded="true"
```

Then I return to the tab fragment after I've made the changes to the database through an Intent.  This forces the tab to refresh every time that I go to it.

Perhaps this will help someone else.